# Add Tag Manager in a Landing Page

Tags: javascript, tags, google-tag-manager

I'm developing a landing page with a partner, who wants to install a TAG on our landing page. I use RD Station and this would be done through advanced editing via Javascript: https://ajuda.rdstation.com/s/article/Instalar-Google-Tag-Manager-em-Landing-Pages?language=pt_BR

However, I would like to know if installing another Google Tag Manager will affect the reading of Google Analytics